Issue with stripe payment using a bank account
I have a code. I used Stripe in live mode. First, I used SetupIntent to set up their account. After that, I stored customer Stripe ID and payment method ID for further use. Then I used PaymentIntent to charge an amount from their set up account. It is working with cards, but for banks, it is not working. Here is the code:
try:
    if payment_method_types == "us_bank_account":
        stripe.PaymentMethod.attach(
            stripe_payment_id,
            customer=customer.stripe_customer_id,
        )
        payment = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            payment_method=stripe_payment_id,
            customer=stripe_customer_id,
            amount=int(1 * 100),
            currency='usd',
            confirm=True,
            return_url='https://my_domain.com/',
            off_session=True,
            payment_method_types=["ach_credit_transfer", "ach_debit", "us_bank_account"]
        )
    else:
        payment = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            payment_method=stripe_payment_id,
            customer=stripe_customer_id,
            amount=int(1 * 100),
            currency='usd',
            confirm=True,
            return_url='https://my_domain.com/',
            off_session=True
        )
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

if payment.status == 'succeeded':
    print("Payment success.")
else:
    print("Payment not success.")

Let me know what to do now? The card works perfectly and shows payment success. However, when I try using a US bank card, it always shows payment not successful.
I attempted to resolve the problem but was unsuccessful, hence I require a proper solution.

Will needs more information to debug. What error does it give? Was it errored on attaching or on PaymentIntent creation + confirmation?
You could grab the errored request id req_xxx from https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs and reach out to Stripe Support for assistance.

You should follow this guide for SetupIntent flow for ACH: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/ach-debit/set-up-payment?platform=web&payment-ui=direct-api
